# C Pointer to arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, nspointerarray

I am learning pointers in C.
When I declare :

```
char c1[] ="hello";
c1[0] = c1[1];
printf("%s\n", c1);
```

It prints out `eello`

But when I do the following:

```
char * c2="hello";
c2[0] = c2[1];
printf("%s\n", c2);
```

it compiles in C# but the program crashes.
Could you help me clarify what happens in the Stack when I execute the program?

Comment: `char *c2 = "hello"` is a string literal. Modifying it will result in UB.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c1[] ="hello";
```

In this line of code, `c1` is declared as a local array of `char`s - and its contents will be placed **on the stack of the function**. Function stacks are modifiable and so `c1[0] = ...` will work.

```
char* c2 = "hello";
```

there's a subtle difference here - `c2` is not an array, but a **pointer** to a string literal. Modifying it is undefined behavior per the standard - in practice, what usually happens is that the `"hello"` string gets placed in the executable's read-only `.data` section - and attempting to modify it triggers a page fault that crashes the program.

Comment: I have 1 question that if we have: c1[]="hello"; and a pointer c2 point to string c1:char *c2=c1; this statement will ok : c2[0] = c2[1]; What is the different beetween statement c2[0] = c2[1];i mean in 2 case c2 still a pointer to the string

Comment: The difference is a pointer to a string, and a pointer to a **string literal**. In `char* c2 = c1` - `c2` will point to `c1`'s memory, which is allocated **on the stack**.